# Is it possible to use Bootstrap in React Js app?

Tags: reactjs

Can I use Bootstrap in my React Js App? if yes, then how do i use? I would be great if you can help me out with some example.

Comment: Did you try reactstrap? https://reactstrap.github.io/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can install bootstrap by `npm i bootstrap` and import the css in App.js file like this              `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`but you can also use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/migrating/) for the pre-created bootstrap component:

```
npm i react-bootstrap
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use bootstrap in react

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
 or yarn add react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

import this in app.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```